# Predicting unobservable data using classification modeling?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, classification, logistic-regression

I have a dataset of teacher evaluations. The question is "how can the instructor improve?" I want to be able to classify whether the comment made by the student is a suggestion or not. I have labeled a little over 1000 observations, 1 if it is a suggestion and 0 if it is not.

Here is some of my code:

```
df2= df[df['suggestion_improve_instructor']>=0]

df2['text']=df2['How_instructor_improve'].str.lower()

def process_text(text):
    #1 Remove punctuation from text
    #2 Remove stopwords
    #3 return a list of clean text words
    
    #1 
    nopunc=[char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]
    nopunc= ''.join(nopunc)
    
    #2
    clean_words = [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords.words('english')]
    
    #3
    return clean_words
    
 
# show the tokenization

df2['text'].head(15).apply(process_text)

# Convert a collection of text to a matrix of tokens
messages_bow= CountVectorizer(analyzer=process_text).fit_transform(df2['text'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(messages_bow, df2['suggestion_improve_instructor'], test_size=0.20, random_state=0)
                                 
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)

y_log_pred= clf.predict(X_test)
```

Doing all of this gives me an accuracy of 91%.

I want to use my model to classify the rest of the comments that I did not label myself. However, when I try to input all of the other observations:

```
bow= CountVectorizer(analyzer=process_text).fit_transform(df['text'])
prediction= clf.predict(bow)

I get the error:
ValueError: X has 5955 features per sample; expecting 2026
```

I know it's because the bag of words of the bigger set of comments is much bigger than the bag of words used to train the model. I just don't know how I can fix this.

What can I do to solve this or is there a better way to use my model to predict unlabeled data with the model I have?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you train a model with a set of N features, the prediction needs to have the same columns as the data that you used in the training phase. i.e your train set had 2026 features (words) and you are predicting on set with 5955 features.

the solution will just be to use transform without fitting again the countVectorizer . i.e use the bow you already fitted in the training phase to transform your text :

```
bow= messages_bow.transform(df['text'])
prediction= clf.predict(bow)
```

As a start, I would try first to use Naive Bays instead of logistic regression and see if it helps. Second, you can see if tf-idf method can increase your accuracy. (btw, accuracy might not be a good metric here, try AUC or F1 )

Then, you can try to use some more complex methods such as classifying over word vectors (read about word2vec, glove, etc).

If none helps, and your unlabeled distribution is too different from the training set, then you might need to label some more samples.